# Parameterization of permissions in rbac

Tags: php, database, authentication, permissions, rbac

explain challenge:

UserTable

```
UID | Username              | etc
-----------------------------------------
 1  |  myBlogAdmin          |  my etc
 2  |  mySportNewsAdmin     |  my etc
```

GroupTable

```
GID |     name       
------------------------
 5  |  blogManager  
 6  |  onlySportCategoryManager
```

GroupUserTable

```
GUID | GID    | UID
------------------------
 1   |  5     |  1
 2   |  6     |  2
```

PermissionTable

```
 PID | name    
------------------------
 1   |  addPost
```

PermissionGroupTable

```
PGID | GID    | PID |
------------------------
 1   |  5     |  1  |
 1   |  6     |  1  | //but only on specified category (sport)
```

group id 6 only access to sport category.
This problem is not just about the category.

Access to some topicCategories in the forum module
Access to some bookCategories in the library module
Access to postCategories  in the blog module

is there standard method?
what is best method:

method 1:
build new permission when new category generated ( whene generate Sport category => create new permission that called "addPost_post_sport_11" [permission name + madule name + category name + category id])

method 2:
build table PermissionOnTable

```
 PID | Group id | permission id | table                 |   run on 
------------------------
 1   |  5        |  1           |  post_category_table  |0(all)
 1   |  6        |  1           |  post_category_table  |6(sport)
```

Comment: Building new permissions on the fly is something you'll want to avoid. But what is the actual problem that you're trying to solve? You're generating a new sport category, sure. Your `onlySportCategoryManager` should have access to all sports, so should gain access to access to this. But is the new sport category a row in the `Sport` table.... or is it its own table? Assuming the former, your `onlySportCategoryManager` will *already* have access to it.

Comment: @ObsidianAge sport post stored in post table... every one can't access every post .... i want create permission on `set` .... in post table set is category... in user tabe set is group (for example in `leave management` user1 can verify user of group2 leave)(for example in `Letter Writing system` user1 can send mail to user of group3 )

Comment: all permission sesyem work like this: `$canViewPost = $user->can('read', $post);` ..... but which post??? how can do it?

Comment: Just use ABAC (attribute and policy-based access control). XACML will let you do exactly what you're looking for.